# Prove Summation Converge to $\frac{1}{e}$ or find an Upper Bound

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

An experiment can be modeled with these two equations. Let $n$ be an even perfect square. The total number of experiments is given by

$$T = {n \choose \sqrt{n}} {n-\sqrt{n} \choose \sqrt{n}},$$

and the total number of Bads events is given by

$$B = \sum_{d=0}^{\sqrt{n}/2} {n/2 \choose d} {n/2 - d \choose \sqrt{n} - 2d} 2^{\sqrt{n} - 2d} {n-2(\sqrt{n}-d) \choose \sqrt{n}}.$$

I wrote a script and found out that as $n$ gets bigger, $\frac{B}{T} \sim \frac{1}{e}$.

But I don't need a tight bound on these quantities because **I'm trying to prove that the probability of a good event is at least $1/2$.**

Showing that $$1 - \frac{B}{T} \geq \frac{1}{2}.$$

**What I have tried:**

As I'm not sure how (or even if it possible) to simplify theses equations I computed the following:

$$\frac{B}{T} = u_0 + u_1 + u_2 + ... + u_{\sqrt{n}/2}$$

finding out that for a $n \geq 36$ the first $3$ terms are "the ones that matter" from $u_3$ onwards they start to get really small. So maybe a way to prove the probability of a bad event would be something like:

$$\frac{B}{T} = u_0 + u_1 + u_2 + ... + u_{\sqrt{n}/2} \leq u_0 + u_1 + u_2 + (\sqrt{n}/2 - 3) u_3 \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$

But I'm not sure if this is the right way to go, maybe there is some clever argument involving $\frac{1}{e}$.

Any help or tips on how to prove this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you tell us exactly what the experiment is, we have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: The experiment is this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471946/probability-edge-in-matching-contain-element-from-two-disjoints-subsets-mathbb 
My combinatorial argument in the end boils down to calculating $1- B/T$. But I believe there is also a probabilty argument that (1) from the previous question is equal to $1 - 1/e$ because the probability of the event follows a Poisson distribution so $1 - $ zero events (that's where the $1/e$ come from).